# call Second Activity from First Activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Can any one please help me how to go to another activity in android

I know following procedure:
**start activity function.**
What is intent as parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Please read developer.android page on **Intent**.

Comment: please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent is a parameter that used to start activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(<context>,<class>));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
```